# Callback URL not working in Auth0, locally

Tags: authentication, auth0, flask-login

I am trying to configure login using Auth0. As part of the initial steps, I created an application and added Allowed Callback URLs and Allowed Logout URLs. I have no hosted pages in `/login`, `/login-results`, `/logout` routes. I am just trying to learn working of Auth0 by getting the `JWT` token and test it in http://jwt.io/.

[image]

I tried to use the login UI flow which available out of the box in Auth0. I created the login URL as mentioned in this [doc](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#authorize-application) to hit this endpoint

```
GET https://YOUR_DOMAIN/authorize?audience=API_IDENTIFIER&scope=SCOPE&response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback&state=STATE
```

But I am getting this error while executing the endpoint which I created using the credentials of my application with above-mentioned callback URL.

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/login-results#error=access_denied&error_description=Service%20not%20found%3A%20name

[image]

Endpoint which I generated:

```
https://fsnd-kavin.auth0.com/authorize?audience=audiencename&response_type=token&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/login-results
```

What is the actual issue? Am I missing any other configurations?

Comment: I sat for hours with this error and tried various methods but it didn't work. But then I created another tenant, carefully, yes I followed the same steps, it worked. I know its strange, but it worked. As far as I did I had put the same API identifier as audience, and sure that I followed the steps to create an Appilication and API.

Answer (score 1):

> Service Not Found

This error message points to that you passed non existent API identifier as audience. Check that API is created in the API section of Dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, I created that properly and yes I gave the same Identifier as mentioned in the audience parameter. I am sure about this.. @Tanver Hansan